# MySQL: Join more tables with different number of same ids

Tags: mysql, join

Another time here to ask help.

I'm about gonna crazy.

***Note: when I use the ID term, I refer to no-autoincrement IDs. Each IDs identifies a customer***

I have 4 different tables.

1° Table whith Unique ID (12.000 records). This Table is used for First Name, Last name, Date of birth, Address, Mail etc

2° Table with the same Unique ID of the first (12.000 records/same values). This table is used for  other type of data like feedbacks

3° Table with unique ID but isted of 12.000 are only 10, but they has the same values of 1° and 2° table. This tables is used to assign the ID to a User that manages his ID

4° Table whith No-Unique ID. About 6.000 records. In this table I have the same ID values but the number of same ID is from 1 to 5. This table is used for purchases of Customers. So, I have more records whith same ID but with different purchase data, date/time, and so on.

Table 1. (same number of unique ID)
CustomersMaster

```
ID        |Name     |Surname   |mail          |
----------|---------|----------|--------------|
40302025  |Jack     |  Daniel  |  m1@site.com |
40302028  |Martin   |  Scorzese|  m2@site.com |
40302030  |Donald   |  Duck    |  m3@site.com |
40302055  |Eric     |  Clapton |  m4@site.com |
40302074  |Mark     |  Knopfler|  m5@site.com |
```

Table 2. Feedbacks (same number of unique ID, like Table1)

```
ID        |Feedback |
----------|---------|
40302025  |  10     |
40302028  |  8      |
40302030  |  7      |
40302055  |  9      |
40302074  |  10     |
```

Table 3. CustomersToUsers (different number of unique ID)

```
ID        |managed_by|
----------|----------|
40302025  |User001   |
40302028  |User002   |
40302055  |User004   |
40302074  |User004   |
```

Table 4. Purchases. (different number of same ID, sometimes the ID is not present, like exemple)

For Example, in this table the ID 40302074 is not present because the customer has not purchased any product.

```
ID        |ProductCode|
----------|-----------|
40302025  |505        |
40302025  |510        |
40302025  |300        |
40302025  |305        |
40302028  |505        |
40302028  |545        |
40302028  |515        |
40302028  |212        |
40302028  |121        |
40302030  |510        |
40302030  |510        |
40302030  |510        |
40302030  |510        |
40302055  |300        |
40302055  |300        |
40302055  |300        |
```

Now. I tried to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN.`

---

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.SURNAME, A.MAIL, B.FEEDBACK, C.MANAGED_BY, D.PRODUCTCODE 
FROM 


    CUSTOMERSMASTER AS A 

    LEFT OUTER JOIN

    FEEDBACKS AS B ON A.ID = B.ID

    LEFT OUTER JOIN

    CustomersToUsers AS C ON B.ID = C.ID

    LEFT OUTER JOIN

    Purchases AS D ON C.ID = D.ID
```

The result is less number of rows, but if I remove the Purchase table from query (on `SELECT` and on `LEFT OUTER JOIN`) the result is OK

What is wrooooooong :(

Thanks for answers

Carlo

Comment: Change `C.ID = D.ID` to `A.ID = D.ID` in the last join condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `A.ID = D.ID` instead of `C.ID = D.ID` in your last join condition.

Because many of your records in A don't have a related record in C, so C.id will be null and....

Comment: Oh I'm very sorry but I still don't know how StackOverflow works. I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

because you have more than 1 rows in your purchase table, for above query you will get much more rows than **CustomersMaster** table have,

check this link :-  [sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93960/14/0) , maybe this will help you little

Comment: Very Thanks. It's not exactly what I needed, but thanks to you I learned the GROUP_CONCAT function that will help me to create arrays. Yeah!

Answer (score -1):

I'd prefer this way, but it all boils down to what you generally use. For me its more clear and expressive. This should work for the case.

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.SURNAME, A.MAIL, B.FEEDBACK, C.MANAGED_BY, D.PRODUCTCODE 
FROM 


    CUSTOMERSMASTER A, FEEDBACKS B, CustomersToUsers C, Purchases D

  where 
    A.id=B.id && B.id=C.id && C.id= D.id;
```

Comment: :o Holy Ignorance. The easiest solution was this?? I spent a sleepless night behind this query and in the end the simplest solution works perfectly

Comment: but but but but it gives a no-null values... Mark Knoplfler there isn't in response...

Comment: I really like `ANSI Join` syntax, and believe me, you can not do all things using ANSI Joins without it easily.